# What is the order of rebalansing different consumers group in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have Spring Boot App - read from one kafka topic, do something with record, write new result to another topic.

Each topic for reading has different consumer groups. Each topic has **different** MassageListnerContainer with **concurrency equal topic partitions number**, for example 20.
I start all MessageListeners containers one by one. What I expected to see - each consumer group started to rebalance parallel, independent one from each other, but I see that next rebalancing is starting **only after** another consumer group was rebalanced.

Is it normal behaviour and is some way to customize this? Or maybe it's only my app problem?

Comment: I will add that the containers start one after another normally and quickly. Here I deliberately do not parallelize this operation, because it is not necessary. But in the kafka cluster I see in admin panel rebalancing of some consumer group does not begin until another one ends.

Comment: This is probably how Apache Kafka borker(s) works. The rebalance action is out of Spring for Apache Kafka project scope. This one is only for high-level client API: there is nothing in what Spring for Apache Kafka makes some impact for the server side. I added `apache-kafka` tag to your question since it is out of any client scope.

Comment: Have you tried overriding the partition assignor class to do cooperative rebalancing, for example?

Comment: @ArtemBilan is any apache kafka documentation for this behaviour? I tried to find any information but it was without success